# Mysql Add comma between the numbers

Tags: mysql

I have data in my table as below.

```
1042
1234
1234
.
.
```

I want to add comma between the numbers like this

```
1,0,4,2
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
.
.
```

Is there any function to do this in MySQL.

> Note: entry in that column is dynamically change. so can not able
>   hardcore the value.

Any idea thanks in advance.

Comment: can i ask why you need to do that? if the values are seperate, they should have seperate columns

Comment: @Takarii Agreed.  He should avoid creating CSV, and the difficulty in doing what he wants reflects that MySQL does not want to do this.

Comment: there is not direction function available in mysql

Comment: you will have to write custom function to do so.

Comment: Please specify more details about the schema. Is your data coming from different rows of the same column or same row of multiple columns. Based on that you *might* use a `GROUP_CONCAT` or `CONCAT` in a query to fetch comma separated values.

Comment: @SarathChandra. directly i have to deal with the data in the table. the table has data as shown above.

Comment: @Aashick: Is it in the same row of the same column or multiple columns of the same row? Why are the values not put like a one-to-many mapping? Sometimes, you might be better off changing your database design to solve this kind of issue.

Comment: This is a classical [**XY problem**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): you are attempting to ask for a solution for a problem that has its roots elsewhere. Firstly ask yourself (1) why is there a need to explode the four numbers into a comma-separated list and (2) what is the nature of these numbers, and are there better ways to store them (i.e. atomise them into four rows per entry, or into another table, which you can query using JOIN statements).

Comment: @SarathChandra that was the same row of same column. (only one column which hold that value).

Comment: @Aashick: How do you identify if the value 1123 is 11,23 or 1,123 or 112,3 ? Or do you simply want to insert commas irrespective of the numerical meaning and get 1,1,2,3 - meaning the numbers do not have any meaning to you.

Comment: @SarathChandra. their is a requirement to do that, actual values are 1,4,2,3 but they stored that DB as above (1423), from UI it get inserting so in UI change is done. now old data is their that have to change.

Comment: their is no way to hardcore and update that. so i am searching for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this before the entry to the database use below.

```
$oldstring = 123456;
echo $newstring = implode(",", str_split($oldstring));
//output 1,2,3,4,5,6
```